# Как написать программу для распознавания тестов по фотографии?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Есть идея создать что-то на подобии `ZipGrade` (https://www.zipgrade.com/) - это мобильное приложение которое по фотографии сделанной специальной формы распознает ответы на вопросы и считает количество правильных и не правильных ответов. Вопрос заключается в том как можно реализовать приблизительно такой функционал распознавания ответов в форме по фото на `python` (если можно, то показать минимальный пример распознавания по фотографий в формах)?

Comment: Для этого стоит использовать обученную модель компьютерного зрения, я знаю что есть библиотеки с уже обученными моделями, распознающими текст по фото, но не уверен, что есть такие, которые распознают выбранные ответы со специальной формы(посмотрел форму по ссылке). Поэтому есть 2 варианта, либо использовать более простую форму, использующую пары № вопроса - ответ, либо заняться обучением модели самому и научить ее распознавать по фото номер вопроса и ответ. Для этого подойдет библиотека cv2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: 123.png]

Минимальный пример кода:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# загрузка изображения
img = cv2.imread('123.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Бинаризация изображения
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# Поиск внешних контуров 
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
lst = []
for inx, contour in enumerate(reversed(contours), 1):
    # Получение координат и размеров описывающего прямоугольника
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    # Выделение области
    roi = thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    # Подсчет количества черных пикселей внутри прямоугольника
    black_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(roi)
    #print(black_pixels)
    q = 0
    if black_pixels > 2700:
        #print(inx)
        q = 1
    # Отображение результата на изображении
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    lst.append(q)

chunks = [lst[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)]
for inx, chunk in enumerate(chunks,1):
    max_index = chunk.index(1)+1
    print(f'вопрос {inx} ответ {max_index}')


# Отображение результата
cv2.imshow("Result", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

вопрос 1 ответ 3
вопрос 2 ответ 4
```

Comment: спасибо за подробный ответ, а получается по такому же принципу выделения можно будет сделать и отображение не верного ответа?

Comment: и вопрос, будет ли данный код корректно работать при наличии на форме внешнего текста или его также придется программно выделять и удалять для дальнейшей обработки ответов?

Comment: Код работает на моей форме)) на других формах результаты будут некорректны. Один вариант из множества решений задачи. Рекомендую посетить канал https://www.youtube.com/@murtazasworkshop

Comment: понял, большое спасибо за ответ)